Validating recorded sampling probabilities in an unequal probability sample
I have a sample of $n$ objects that was allegedly obtained by drawing from a large population of size $N$, $n$ times with replacement where each object has probability $p_i$ of being selected on each draw. Some items are sampled more than once, and I have counts for each object (most are sampled once, though). Thus we can think of the sampling procedure as drawing from a multinomial distribution with N categories. However, I’m mistrustful of the sampling procedure and would like to test that hypothesis. Are there any standard ways to check this? Naively it seems like you can just do a Chi squared test on the whole population, but in practice this isn’t very attractive because I don’t want to (or perhaps can’t) get the sampling probabilities for the whole population, and also because almost all the counts are 0 or 1. I’ve tried to think of ways to doing a Chi-squared test on just the sample counts, treating it as a multinomial distribution with probabilities $p_i/\sum p_i$ where the sum is over the sample, but this still has the problem that most counts are 1 and it seems very sensitive. Are there any standard ways to do this?

Have you considered the likelihood ratio variant of the chi-squared test?

I'm reading about this now. Would the idea be that this performs better in the presence of small counts?

It might.  The chi-squared test actually performs well in the presence of small expected counts provided there's a lot of them: the usual rule of thumb is only that, and is not a universal limitation on the applicability of the chi-squared test.  Moreover, no matter what statistic you use, you can obtain a p-value through simulating the null distribution.  It's quick and easy to do.
